# Change Language in ZfcUser Module

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm using **ZfcUser** in my Zend 2 Project. But i've to use the italian translation and not the english one.

I've changed in my projects
    module/Application/config/module.config.php
in the translator property and all began italian, not the part of the Module.

In the directory 
    vendor/ZfcUser/src/ZfcUser/language
there's the it_IT.po and it_IT.mo files.

Nothing change. How can chain the language of my application with the module?

MOD1:

I added the **translator** but nothing seem to work

Added code:

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'zfcuser' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => 'ZfcUser\Controller\UserController',
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'zfcuser' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/utente',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'login' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/login',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action'     => 'login',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'authenticate' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/autenticati',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action'     => 'authenticate',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'logout' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/logout',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action'     => 'logout',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'register' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/registrazione',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action'     => 'register',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'changepassword' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/cambia-password',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action'     => 'changepassword',
                            ),
                        ),                        
                    ),
                    'changeemail' => array(
                        'type' => 'Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/cambia-email',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                                'action' => 'changeemail',
                            ),
                        ),                        
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'it_IT',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've downloaded the latest **ZfcUser** and the *.po files are not loaded. Check the **ZfcUser/config/module.config.php**. You'll have to load them the same way as you do in your **Application/config/module.config.php**. When a key can't be matched with a translation file, it uses the key itself, so **$this->translate('Not registered?');** won't find the matching italian string, and it'll use 'Not registered?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In my ZfcUser module the language pack under \ZfcUser\src\ZfcUser\ is in the wrong position, it works putting it in \ZfcUser root